# install yum No module named urlgrabber

Tags: yum

//   install package
      rpm -ivh --force --nodeps python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm
    warning: python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
    Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
       1:python-iniparse        ########################################### [100%]
//    install package
    rpm -ivh --force yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64.rpm
    warning: yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
    error: Failed dependencies:
        python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64
    rpm -ivh --force --nodeps yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64.rpm
    warning: yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
    Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
       1:yum-metadata-parser    ########################################### [100%]
    rpm -ivh --force --nodeps yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch.rpm
    warning: yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
    Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
       1:yum-plugin-fastestmirro########################################### [ 50%]
       2:yum                    ########################################### [100%]
    cd yum-3.4.3
    ./yummain.py update
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./yummain.py", line 28, in 
        from yum import Errors
      File "/download/yum-3.4.3/yum/**init**.py", line 52, in 
        import config
      File "/download/yum-3.4.3/yum/config.py", line 30, in 
        from parser import ConfigPreProcessor, varReplace
      File "/download/yum-3.4.3/yum/parser.py", line 4, in 
        import urlgrabber
    ImportError: No module named urlgrabber

// the end my yum install is faild ,please how to install yum

Answer (score 0):

How it is possible that yum or dnf is not setup on your cent-os ? strange... except if you have a really light docker image or something like that.

Anyway, the RPM package shows there are dependencies ( https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.9/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.html ) You have to install them all (and dependencies of those dependencies ) before running yum successfully.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is wrong, but if you have a linux box based on RPM you should have as starter yum. On the yum side, the link give you "requires" RPM. You need to install them all before installing yum to get yum to work. Remove the "--nodeps" so that you can check package per packages the missing dependencies.

Comment: you mean mississing dependencies? i am try it